# pd.read_excel() replaces blanks with `nan` string, pd.read_csv() uses numpy.nan

Tags: python, pandas

When I create a `DataFrame` with

```
pd.read_excel(my_excel_file, dtype=str)
```

blank cells in the spreadsheet are replaced with the string `nan`. On the other hand, a `DataFrame` generated from

```
pd.read_csv(my_csv_file, dtype=str)
```

replaces blanks with `numpy.nan` objects. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question on *Why is this?* When using `dtype=str` to read the Excel File using `pd.read_excel`, the result obtained is not consistent with what you get when using `pd.read_csv`. The main reason or you can say, advantage in replacing blank cells with `numpy.nan` objects when using `pd.read_csv` is that it facilitates you to use `pd.isna`, which would only work with `numpy.nan` objects, and not otherwise with just `nan`.

There has been a lot of discussion pertaining to this, and it can be said this functionality in turn allows consistency to be maintained between `pd.read_csv` and `pd.read_excel`. You can read more about the discussion on the Github Page for Pandas, where some debate has been going on in this regard at [read_excel with dtype=str converts empty cells to the string 'nan' #20377](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20377)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a `na_values` attribute to `read_excel`.

```
df = pd.read_excel(my_excel_file, na_values=[''], dtype=object)
```